# MySql erroe 1052 it says P_No in field is ambiguoous

Tags: mysql

I get an error saying `P_No` is ambiguous.

```
select P_No from passenger p join booking b1 on b1.P_No=p.P_No
join flightbooking f on b1.Booking_No=f.Booking_No where f.F_Code='F001';
```

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: I've edited your question to format the code an include a question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have the same field in both tables so without specifying a table it will give you this error.

You can use this if you want to select the field from `passenger` table:

```
select p.P_No from passenger p join booking b1 on b1.P_No=p.P_No
join flightbooking f on b1.Booking_No=f.Booking_No where f.F_Code='F001';
```